# How to debug a SSL https hang ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, https

Although my SSL certificate didn't expire, and nothing was changed in the AWS ELB that has it configured, suddenly access to my site through HTTPS hangs and dies in a ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. When debugging I noticed it doesn't even reach the PHP script.

How can I debug the path between the browser, the certificate in the ELB, and my server to see where it's "stuck"?

Is there a log for Apache on Ubuntu that I can view requests to the SSL port?

Answer (score 3):

You can enable logging in apache:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_engine.log
    LogLevel debug
</IfModule>
```

and use [openssl s_client](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html) to check how ssl negotiation looks from clientside, e.g.:

```
openssl s_client -connect stackoverflow.com:443
```

Basic TCP connectivity (not related to ssl) can be checked with `telnet`:

- layers 1-4 work well, connection established:

  ```
  $ telnet stackoverflow.com 443
  Trying 104.16.35.249...
  Connected to stackoverflow.com.
  Escape character is '^]'.
  ```
- resolve host, but cannot handshake:

  ```
  $ telnet stackoverflow.com 443
  Trying 104.16.37.249...
  ```
- cannot resolve host:

  ```
  $ telnet stackoverflow.com 443
  telnet: could not resolve stackoverflow.com/443: Name or service not known
  ```

Comment: When running openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443 it just hangs without any output. (running the same for stackoverflow shows debug information). What does that mean regarding where the request is stuck? I'm guessing in such a case adding the ErrorLog in .htaccess won't help, right?

Comment: It actually doesn't hang indefinitely, I finally get a `connect: Operation timed out
connect:errno=60`

Comment: Then `telnet mydomain.com 443` to confirm the port is open and the server listens on it. [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html)/ [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or any other sniffer to get detailed information on packet level, if handshake actually happens.

Comment: The `telnet mydomain.com 443` also hangs without any output. What does that mean regarding where it's stuck?

Comment: On TCP handshake. One of the packets from  `SYN` - `SYN,ACK` - `ACK` sequence didn't make it through. The 2nd one is returned by the server, so it is either a firewall, or server does not listen on the port/interface. The problem lays on transport layer and is not related to ssl libraries/certificates.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. When I `telnet`, doesn't it start by going through the AWS Load Balancer that has the certificate installed and only then moves on to my server? Because there's no SSL error displayed, you're saying it didn't even reach the certificate, thus it's stuck at a more basic transport layer between the DNS and the Load Balancer?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest to test DNS on its own though. `telnet` had to show which IP it was using trying to establish connection, but it is out of scope of the question.

Comment: Is the DNS port sensitive? `telnet mydomain.com 80` still works.. Can you maybe direct me to a relevant question for testing DNS?

Comment: No, if port 80 works, it means domain has been resolved, and the server is up and running.

Comment: So I'm still confused.  The `telnet 80` works, `telnet 443` doesn't and also doesn't show which IP it was using. So what does that mean about where it's getting stuck?

Comment: Updated the answer with examples

Comment: But my case is actually a timeout. Is that the same as `cannot resolve host:
` ?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with local system. Can you reproduce it from another   system/network?

Comment: Hi @Noam. Recently I am moving an app from http to https and I happen to face this same issue. Please did you manage to solve it. http works well but not https